# In Recycler View with multiple view types items duplicating on scrollup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with multiple view types and pagination enabled. Scrolling up after two pages the items are not holding the view and are duplicating. I have implemented getItemId return unique id and getViewtype return unique value. Also have the the adapter's setHasStableIds to true. Looking forward for any help. 
Thank you.

**getItemId**

```
if (postList.get(position).getId()== null){
        return position;
    } else{
        return postList.get(position).getId();
    }
```

**getItemViewType**

```
 if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("contest")){
            return TYPE_CONTEST;
  } else if(postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("suggestion")){
            return TYPE_SUGGESTION;
        } else{
            return TYPE_POST_POLL;
        }
    } else{
        return TYPE_HEADER;
       }
```

Comment: your getItemId() doesn't seem to return unique ids to me

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isValidPosition(position)) {
        Dataset d = mDataset[position];
        if ("contest".equals(d.getViewType())) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_CONTEST;
        } else if ("suggestion".equals(d.getViewType())) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_SUGGESTION;
        }
        // all other cases here
    }
    // default type
    return VIEW_TYPE_CONTEST;
}
```

and then :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Dataset d = mDataset[position];

    if (holder instanceof ContestVH) {
        ContestDataset contest = (ContestDataset) d;
        ContestVH vh = (ContestVH) holder;
        // bind your contest views here
    } else if (holder instanceof SuggestionVH) {
        SuggestionDataset suggestion = (SuggestionDataset) d;
        SuggestionVH vh = (SuggestionVH) holder;
        // bind your suggestion views here
    }
    // all other cases here
}
```

this way your String view type is your only source of truth.

Comment: postList.get(position).getId() <-- In getItemId this is the part where I use my post's ID as unique value. Please let me know if there is any other way

Comment: As I wrote, if null you rely on position (1, 3, 5), if not null you rely on id (1, 3, 5?). This makes the id potentially non-unique. But you don't have any need to uniquely identify your datasets by unique id, because they are already uniquely identified by position. What you need to do, is to ensure that for each data type you have (therefore for each different type of viewholder) you can bind the dataset to the corresponding view. See my code snippet, it works.

Comment: Okay, have 4 different ViewHolders, but problem with my dataset is that for every type my model is same. Any help?

Comment: Also the problem comes when is paginate from page 1 to 2, when I add new data to my existing dataset

Comment: @user2837607 4 different types of view holders means you have 4 different types of layouts, right? Like in 1 there is one extra view, and so on. They differ. Your datasets instead can easily be the same, no problem (I assume some will contain nulls or meaningless fields), but you can still differentiate them by Java class types: Dataset is your (empty) parent, then you will have 4 children inheriting from it: ContestDataset, SuggestionDataset, and so on. Each more specialized dataset should IMHO be filled only with the needed fields. This way code is clear and clean, and you trustly bind them

Comment: "when I add new data to my existing dataset" -> it depends how you add the data, and also how would you ensure the added part has unique ids which are not already used by the other part?

Comment: Thank a lot, it worked making the classes separate. And returning just position in getItemId.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination in recyclerview you should use onScrollListener this

```
recyclerList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        boolean isLast = isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView);  //get last displayed item
        if (loading && isLast) {  //this check if your data is loading and if its last list item list will not load again
            loading = false;

            //get your data according to page count it will refresh your recycler list 

        }
    }
});
```

because in pagination you can get data from Api on page scroll in recycler view. So data will come in chunks according to page count. For this behaviour you can use on scroll listener in recycler list and refresh data on scroll of list until last item of list arrived.
i hope it will help you  :)